# How can I compile different .tex file on click on typeset in TeXShop? (MacTeX 2011)

Tags: compiling, texshop

My problem is that I want to have different `.tex` files for the preamble, the presentation aroundings (my target is a `beamer` PDF file) and the content of the presentation.

Mostly I'll be working on the content file. I even think about partitioning this content `.tex` file into several chapter files for a better overview. My problem with this solution is that I have to open the `presentation.tex` file to typeset the whole `beamer` PDF for looking at the results of my previous changes on the content files. (My `presentation.tex` file includes the preamble and the content.)

Is there any way to get TeXShop to always typeset one particular file (my `presentation.tex`) although I'm currently working on a different one (e.g. the `content.tex`)?

A shortcut? A command in the `.tex` file? An option in TeXShop? Anything?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

TeXshop, like TeXworks, allows you to define some stuff by special comments at the beginning of a file. To define a master file, add

```
% !TEX root = path/to/root.tex
```

to the beginning of your file. This will cause `root.tex` to be compiled instead of the current file.

Comment: Note that capitalizing matters. I had a line with "TeX" and it did not work with TeXShop.

Comment: Thank you - that was very useful. In case it helps, here are links to [the manual](http://ex.osaka-kyoiku.ac.jp/~fujii/EX/TeXworks-manual-en.pdf) and [a list of special comments](https://www.texdev.net/2011/03/24/texworks-magic-comments/)