# Working on a chapter at a time

Tags: chapters

I'm writing a document which I want to split into several chapters, each chapter in its own `.tex` file.  My main document has the preamble and I use `\include` commands to include each chapter.  My question is, when I'm working on the chapter, say, `ch1.tex`, is it possible to compile `ch1.tex` so I can see the output and continue working on it that way until I'm done with it?  As I understand it, `ch1` should have no preamble, right?  Would I have to make a common preamble file so that I can `\include` it in each chapter when I work on it, compile as necessary, and then comment it out when I'm ready to put the entire document together including all chapters?

My apologies if this question is confusing, or if it has been answered before.

EDIT: Per request of comments below, the editor I'm using is TeXShop on Mac OS X Yosemite

Comment: Related: [Making one PDF file from multiple PDFs or TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155867/5764)

Comment: Also: `\includeonly{ch1}` for example, to prevent the inclusion of other chapters, for better/quicker editing

Comment: don't comment out the chapters you are not working on just use `\includeonly` to work on one chapter while allowing cross references and numbering to be correct for the chapters that you are not using.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If I go with the `\include` option, then I always have to have two files open.  First file is the `ch1.tex` file, but the file I compile is the overall main file.  I imagine that could get kind of annoying.  I took a look at the subfiles package @Werner mentioned, and I think that might solve it

Comment: Most editors will let you run the main document while editing the chapter, just needs to be told in a comment or configuration which is the master file. Id use \include, it is built in to latex and much much simpler and works well for this use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks, looking at your profile it certainly seems like you know what you're talking about, so I'm going to go with your advice.  Could you describe briefly the work flow if I go with the `\include` method?  I have a main document which has the `\include`s, and I'm editing the `ch1.tex`. Now, when I want to visually see the progress I've made, I have to go back to the main file to compile, right? I don't compile `ch1.tex`. Did I get that right?

Comment: you need to run latex on the master file but most editors let you run that from a single keystroke while editing the chapter, eg the editor I use, emacs allows comments like `% -*- TeX-master: "../master.tex" -*-` that tell it that all the document level commands like latex, bibtex etc should use the file `../master.tex` even if the current file is `cha1.tex`

Comment: If you edit your question to mention which editor you are using to write your files, someone who uses that editor can answer your question directly (about how to set the master file and about how to use `\include` and `\includeonly` properly).

Comment: @jon: I added the editor I'm using. Would appreciate a quick demonstration how to set up the master file

Comment: See [How can I compile different .tex file on click on typeset in TeXShop? (MacTeX 2011)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39208)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: That is exactly the solution I was looking for, *perfect*.  If someone wants to put this in the form of an answer, I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: If you do want modify open/modify the main file to compile only the chapter you are working, then you are searching for `docmute` or `standalone` packages. [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136727/11604) there are a MWE (with `beamer` and `\input` instead of your  document  class with `\include`,  but that should be irrelevant).