# A Question in Compiling book Class

Tags: compiling, texmaker, external-files, texworks

I am writing my thesis using `book` class. And I use `include` function so that I can have separate files for each chapter. One problem with this is that I must click `run` button in the main file. If I click `run` button in chapter files, error occurs. I learned that this is not a problem in TeX Studio so long as all the files is open. But I am using TeXWork and TeXMaker. So I always to find the right button to click, which is annoying. Is there an easy fix for this problem, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using TeXMaker to write my thesis, and after trying with `include` and `input`, that had the problem you mentioned, I ended up using the `subfiles` package, in this way:

**Main document**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\subfile{./Chapter} % Chapter file's name (and position)

\end{document}
```

**Chapter document**

```
\documentclass[./MainDocument.tex]{subfiles} % Main document file's name (and position)

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

In this way I can compile a single chapter. I saw that not all the properties (such as line spacing or headers/footers) of the main document are passed to the subfile; however, I compile the subfile only to check the *content* of the chapter, while I check the style and so on when I run the main document.

Comment: How did you find that out, please? Only curious.

Comment: @LaTeXfan Actually I don't remember, since it was when I started organizing my thesis files _and_ learning LaTeX at the same time, so I was googling like a thousand problems a day! :-)

Answer (score 9):

Both Texmaker and TeXworks are able to do this.

- **Texmaker**: With the main file open, select *Options --> Define Current Document as master document* ([How to best use and compile multiple .tex files as part of same final document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94414/how-to-best-use-and-compile-multiple-tex-files-as-part-of-same-final-document))
- **TeXworks**: At the top of the chapter file, write

  ```
  %!TeX root = /path/to/main/file
  ```

  For example, if `main.tex` is in the same folder as `chapter1.tex`, write `%!TeX root = main.tex`. If `main.tex` is in the folder above, you can write `%!TeX root = ../main.tex`.

  See http://www.texdev.net/2011/03/24/texworks-magic-comments/

Comment: Is there a similar way to achieve this for TeXShop, please?

Comment: @LaTeXfan [How can I compile different .tex file on click on typeset in TeXShop? (MacTeX 2011)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39208)