# TeXShop shortcut

Tags: texshop

I have a file called `draft.tex`.  In it are

```
\documentclass…
\usepackage…
   …
some macros
   …
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\input{sec1.tex}
\input{sec2.tex}
   …
bibliography stuff
\end{document}
```

the files `sec1.tex` & `sec2.tex` look like

```
\section{title of sec}
text
```

I would like to edit `sec1.tex` and then make the document.  The only way I know how to do this is to change the editor focus to a window containing `draft.tex`, and then typesetting.  Is there a way of doing this in one step, without having to change the editor window focus?  Even better, without opening `draft.tex` at all?  Apologies if this has been answered before.  I couldn't find it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39207/134574?

Comment: see answers AND comments here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450546/in-texstudio-how-to-compile-only-the-subfile and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/using-subfiles-package-with-sty-files

Comment: Thank you both.  %! TEX root=draft is brilliant.  Subfiles is a bit much for my current need, but good to know about for larger projects.